# Arbitrary Sorting on the basis of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Assume there is ID and Value in a table and we are to put numbers to the runs of rows that have consecutive id's and the same value.

Example table:

```
id | value    run_id
====+=================
  1 |   7         1
  2 |   7         1
----+-----------------
  3 |   0         2
----+-----------------
  5 |   0         3
----+-----------------
  6 |  -5         4
----+-----------------
  7 |   7         5
  8 |   7         5
  9 |   7         5
```

Maybe I am missing something basic here but my solution here is a very bad workaround and is falling the test cases.

```
SELECT id,value, run_id, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY run_id ASC) AS run_id2 FROM(
SELECT
id,value,
CASE 
  WHEN LAG(id,1) OVER(ORDER BY id) IS null THEN id
  WHEN LAG(id,1) OVER(ORDER BY id) = id-1 AND LAG(value,1) OVER(ORDER BY id)=value AND LAG(value,2) OVER(ORDER BY id)=value THEN LAG(id,2) OVER(ORDER BY id)
  WHEN LAG(id,1) OVER(ORDER BY id) = id-1 AND LAG(value,1) OVER(ORDER BY id)=value THEN LAG(id,1) OVER(ORDER BY id)
  ELSE (LAG(id,1) OVER(ORDER BY id))+1
END AS run_id
FROM(
SELECT  
e1.*
FROM entries AS e1
ORDER BY id) x
ORDER BY id)y
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add a tag for only the DBMS you are really using

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the previous `id` and `value` of each row with `LAG()` window function and compare them to the current row's values.
Window function `SUM()` with a `CASE` expression will return what you want:

```
SELECT id, value,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_id = id - 1 AND value = prev_value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) run_id
FROM (
  SELECT id, value, 
         LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_id,
         LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_value
  FROM entries
) t  
ORDER BY id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f59eb7f2fb422ac7f423e3d6587d54f).
Results:

| id | value | run_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | -5 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 7 | 5 |
| 9 | 7 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using only one `lag()`:

```
SELECT e.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN prev_value_id = id - 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) as run_id
FROM (SELECT e.*, 
             LAG(id) OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY id) as prev_value_id
      FROM entries e
     ) e 
ORDER BY id;
```

The logic is simple.  A row is in the same group as the previous row only if the `value` is the same and the id is one more than the previous `id`.